# Call Signatures example on TS Handbook

Tags: typescript

I am reading the Typescript Handbook and, right now, I am currently stuck at Call Signatures subsection. In the example given:

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};

function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}
```

I cannot figure out in TS Playground how to invoke the `doSomething` function. I tried the below but it is not working.

```
doSomething({ description: "The code", (5): false})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `DescribableFunction` is first and foremost a function that takes a single `number` input and returns a `boolean`.  It also has a `string`-valued `description` property.

Since TypeScript 3.1, and as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#26368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26368), you've been allowed to [add properties to functions after their declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions) without running into compiler warnings. So you can make a `DescribableFunction` relatively straightfowardly.

Here's how you could do it with a function statement:

```
function greaterThanTen(someArg: number) {
    return someArg > 10;
}
greaterThanTen.description = "greaterThanTen";

doSomething(greaterThanTen); // "greaterThanTen returned false"
```

And here's how you could do it with a function expression:

```
const isEven: DescribableFunction = someArg => someArg % 2 === 0;
isEven.description = "isEven"

doSomething(isEven); // "isEven returned true"
```

If you want a one-liner, you could use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to add properties to a target and return the augmented target, which TypeScript represents as the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the function type and the added property objects.  (This worked even before TypeScript 3.1.)  Observe:

```
const isNegative = Object.assign(
    (someArg: number) => someArg < 0,
    { description: "isNegative" }
);
doSomething(isNegative); // "isNegative returned false"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#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)

Answer (score 1):

Functions with additional properties seem unergonomic; at least you cannot declare them using a single plain object.

This is one way:

```
const fn = ((x: number) => false) as DescribableFunction;
fn.description = 'description';
doSomething(fn);
```

Comment: Are you sure about this?  [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69509086/2887218) shows three ways of getting a `DescribableFunction` without needing type assertions.

Comment: @jcalz: For some reason I had errors without the additional assertion when I wrote this answer. Now I tested it again and it was not necessary, maybe something about the compiler settings was off. I also vaguely remembered that there had been this change to allow adding properties to functions...

Comment: I think parentheses might affect it for some reason, (e.g., `const fn = ((x: number) => false)` will fail while `const fn = (x: number) => false` will succeed).  I might open a bug report about it

Comment: @jcalz Oh, that is a bit odd indeed

Comment: Yeah, just opened [microsoft/TypeScript#46284](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46284) about it.  My guess is that it's not important enough to be addressed, but I didn't see it mentioned anywhere already.