# what typescript type would an anonymous function be?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types, typescript-declarations

thanks i'm learning to declare functions in `.d.ts` files

#### my javascript has

```js
function generate(romeo) {
  return function(juliet) {
    return romeo + juliet 
  }
}
```

#### typescript declaration

```
  /**
   * Function that accepts strings and returns composed function.
   */
  export function generate(romeo: string): (juliet: string) => string;
```

### object?

- found an `object` type about being non primitive
- didn't find any `function` type
- *What types would be legit?*

Comment: Depends on what the function *does*. The type of a function would match its signature. If it takes a number and produces a string, that's different to a function that takes a string and returns a number.

Comment: Are you familiar with the docs on [function type expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions)?

Comment: ok updating now

Comment: "*didn't find any `function` type*" well, there is `Function`. But it just accepts any signature. It's best avoided if you have any other signature in mind.

Comment: thanks yall just updated with strings. still confused.

Comment: What helps is to have an IDE or TS Playground (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) for example. Paste your javascript definition, maybe add types to the parameters, and hover the name of the function. It should show you. It should be along the lines of [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsHsDcFMCdQHNYDsEEMAusBQAzAV1QGMsBLSVZNTHACnkgFtZIAuUAZy3nNSQBKUAG9coUPFhZC8akVIUq9AFaEANuWmcefAcLESJUmXMks2oANSg1m6aHGgAvrle4PCspWop08bFgAJkYLDm5efiFOVQ0tLB1I-VAAXgA+CL0kUScTWXlib2U7eMSsgydjaXzzVkhrWziHJ1dXIA).

Comment: maybe someday but currently just tryna support typescript on opensource javascript https://github.com/ryanve/eol/pull/32

Comment: thanks i think i got it [from tthe example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=1#code/PTAEAsHsDcFMCdQHNYDsEEMAusBQAzAV1QGMsBLSVZNTHACnkgFtZIAuUAZy3nNSQBKUAG9coUPFhZC8akVIUq9AFaEANuWmcefAcLESJUmXMks2oANSg1m6aHGgAvrle4PCspWop08bFgAJkYLDm5efiFOVQ0tLB1I-VAAXgA+CL0kUScTWXlib2U7eMSsgydjaXzzVkhrWziHJ1dXIA) and updated my declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As VLAZ points out in the comments, the type `Function` exists, but it's not very useful: The point of TypeScript is to have certainty about the types that are returned, and Function does not indicate its parameters or return value.

As in the docs on [function type expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions), you can define a function type like this:

```
type FunctionType = (param1: SomeParameter) => SomeReturnValue;
```

For your case, that would look like this:

```
/**
 * Function that accepts strings and returns composed function.
 */
export function generate(romeo: string): (juliet: string) => string;
```

You'll need to specify *some* kind of return value in order for TypeScript to recognize this as a function type, which could be `any` or `unknown` but ideally will be a more specific type like `string` above. (As usual, if the function is intended to not have a useful return value, then `void` is appropriate.) There is also a way to specify a [Function that has additional properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69504538/1426891), which is described in the docs as [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures).

Answer (score 2):

### As type alias

```
type Fn = (s1: string) => (s2: string) => string
```

This is probably the nicest way to read it: Function that takes a string `s1` and returns another function which takes a string `s1`. The second function returns a string.

The advantage here is that the function notation is consistent.

Can also be written with extra grouping brackets if more clarity is needed: `type Fn = (s1: string) => ((s2: string) => string)`

### As interface

```
interface Fn {
    (s1: string): (s2: string) => string
}
```

It means the same thing as above. It is (at least in my eyes) more confusing to read because of the mix of `:` and `=>` to denote return values.

### As part of the definition of the function

```
function generate(romeo: string): (juliet: string) => string {
  return function(juliet: string): string {
    return romeo + juliet 
  }
}
```

If you do not really need a separate type for it. Note that the names of the parameter in the type annotation and the actual function definition do not need to match. The following is equivalent:

```
function generate(romeo: string): (s: string) => string {
  return function(juliet: string): string {
    return romeo + juliet 
  }
}
```

If you do not have the [`explicit-function-return-types`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md) linter rule from TypeScript ESLint (or equivalent), then you can let TypeScript infer the types:

```
function generate(romeo: string) {
  return function(juliet: string) {
    return romeo + juliet 
  }
}
```